# How to access DSL-created KTable/GlobalKTable using Processor API?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I am using a Processor API (PAPI) topology.

Is it possible to access a KTable (or GlobalKTable) created with DSL from  within the Processor API (even if read-only)?

I.e. using the:

```
val builder = new StreamsBuilder()
val KTable = builder.table("topicname")
```

I get a KTable, but the Topology only allows you to use [addStateStore](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/Topology.html#addStateStore-org.apache.kafka.streams.state.StoreBuilder-java.lang.String...-) with a StoreBuilder, not the KTable itself.

```
.addStateStore(myStoreBuilder, MY_PROCESSOR_NAME)
```

So I could build one by doing this:

```
def keyValueStoreBuilder[K, V](storeName: String, keySerde: Serde[K], valueSerde: Serde[V]): StoreBuilder[KeyValueStore[K, V]] = {
Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(
  Stores.persistentKeyValueStore(storeName),
  keySerde,
  valueSerde)
```

}

But, how to cleanly obtain the `storeName` in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a `KTable` it will automatically create a store internally, with a generated name. (You can get the name via `Topology#describe()`). You can also assign a name to the store via `table()` method using `Materialized` parameter.

It's a little unclear to me, what you mean by "access a KTable within the Processor API" though? If you mean "access the KTable store within a `Processor`" you can use `Topology#connectProcessorAndStateStores()` to give the processor access to the store. Note, that the processor should never write into the KTable store, as the `table()` operator is responsible to maintain the table's state. If you do write into the store, there are not guarantees and you might loose data in case of a failure.

Comment: **Name**: Yep, I meant how to get the generated name through API, not constructing it somehow with "appName-stateStore-number" (note the "cleanly" word in my question, hehe). 
So, the name given via `Materialized.as("queryable-store-name")` is the one looked for when connecting processor and statestores? Cool, I thought that was only for IQ.
**Usage**: Yes, it's for reading. Any writes should be sent to the underlying topic which the store is built from (what I actually want is to inherit the fault-tolerance the underlying, compact, nondelete topic has).

Comment: @Matthias J. Sax +1 YOU STRIKE AGAIN! :D

Comment: @Matthias J. Sax How I can access to store from underlying node? 
`streamBuilder.stream("topic").processValues(() -> new MappingProcessor<>(mapper::map), "STORE").totable(Materialized.as("STORE"));` I receive `Invalid topology: StateStore STORE is not added yet.`

Comment: You cannot pass in `"STORE"` directly into `processValue` because, as the error message indicates, the store is not know yet. Instead, after calling `build()` you can use `connectProcessorAndStateStores()` on the created `Topology` afterwards (you might want to set an explicit name for the `processValues()` processor passing in a `Named` parameter.